# Looking for a sound library for Java

Tags: java, audio

I'm working on a OpenGL game in Java and I want to incorporate sound.

I've done some ferreting, and having some trouble finding something.  I've seen that JOAL is now defunct, and there's a popular 3D Sound Engine (paulscode) which seems a bit complicated, and there were references to JOrbis but I wasn't sure it was what I wanted.

I will settle for Ogg or WAV format, it's just for a little 2D game so it doesn't have to be super hi-fi quality, just something the players can hear.  I would like sound FX and also music.

Comment: JOAL isn't defunct, it's actively maintained, please look at xranby's answer.

Answer (score 2):

How should we know what you want if you don't know yourself?

For PCM encoded WAV files, you can use JavaSound directly, which is part of the standard Java API (javax.sound). For Vorbis files, there are several Java decoders available. JOrbis as you already mentioned is one, [J-Ogg](http://www.j-ogg.de/) another and [Xiph](http://www.xiph.org/) has also recently released a Java libraries for the Vorbis decoder.

Comment: The Xiph Java library is a bit hidden. They just offer pure downloads [link](http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis-java/). Also I assembled JOrbis, VorbisSPI and Tritonus-Share into a single library, making it a bit more comfortable. [link](http://www.twelvepm.de/vorbis/)

Answer (score 1):

JOAL is maintained and available from JogAmp

http://jogamp.org/joal/www/

http://jogamp.org/joal-demos/www/